# What do to when you are reaching the document size limit?

Tags: couchbase

If you develop an marketplace and every user can create products then the limits can reached sometimes.

I have read ebay makes 300k write per second so the document size limit can be reached at some minutes or do I have understand something wrong ?

I create a collection products and create recommendation in a seperate collections but if you have a marketplace you store all products in one collection. This limit can be reached in a certain time

Do you store all products that are created in one document ? Then the size limit 20MB can be reached, if you create a new collection for each product then also the limit 1000 can be reached so how the others do it ?

can someone enlighten me ? Maybe I have misunderstood something

Comment: `I have read ebay makes 300k write per second so the document size limit can be reached at some minutes or do I have understand something wrong ?` I don't see how the number of writes per second has _anything_ to do with the document size limit. `Do you store all products that are created in one document?` Why would you do this?

Comment: @tkausl So I can create a document , the number of documents are limitless ?

Comment: "Limitless" might be a bit much :) But there is no hard limit to number of documents in Couchbase. You could have 300,000 documents, each representing a single product, for example.

Comment: @MatthewGroves but what you do when you have 5-10billion documents so maybe in a certain time if you are an big player that can be reached so what is the solution there ?

Comment: As always, it depends on a lot of factors, but that's a nice problem to have :) There are some "big players" who are using Couchbase at very large scale: LinkedIn, PayPal, eBay, Zynga, and more.

Comment: @MatthewGroves for what use case use eBay couchbase ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's user profiles, session, caching, and possibly many others. Check out YouTube and Google for some material on ebay and many other retail/ecommerce use cases: https://www.couchbase.com/use-cases/retail-and-ecommerce/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a size limit per document (20mb), but there is no limit on the number of documents. Yes, there are some limits on the number of scopes and collections. However, a collection can contain many documents. It would not make sense to create a single collection per document. So, in your use case, you might have a "products" collection, a "user profile" collection, an "invoice" collection, etc. And each of those collections could contain many, many documents.

There are practical limits, of course. But currently, Couchbase can handle terabytes of data, especially with the newer [magma engine](https://www.couchbase.com/blog/magma-next-gen-document-storage-engine/).